# Background Image rendering issues in rails 4.1

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I am having trouble understanding how to troubleshooting why my browsers(google chrome and safari) are ignoring the background image. I can see the url built correctly in the dev tools, however it is struck out (the important override still fails here too). Here is my code:

```
body {
  background-image: image-url('blue.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed 
}
```

the image is stored in app/assets/images.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try removing image-url and just using url

```
body {
 background-image: url('blue.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the image as a background instead of a background-image:

```
body {
  background: asset_url('blue.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  color: ...
  margin: ...
  padding: ...
}
```

I do not understand why this works however.